# Chapter heading at the right-hand side

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I want a specific chapter heading as in the picture below
(Chapter heading at the right-hand side, but section  heading at the left-hand side)
Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The solution of egreg is good for the standard class but we don't know your documentclass.

Comment: Egregs solution works well. If you want to change the format after table of contents etc. you can call the new definitions after `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Dear Marco Daniel, I want References heading to be at the left-hand side too. But it is after \mainmatter and my definitions. Can you help me?

Comment: Please see the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `titlesec` package and its `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filleft\Large}
  {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
  {5ex}
  {\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-15pt}
  {60pt}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
Bla
\end{document}
```

The line `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` has been added just for showing the result.

[image]

---

Here an approach to use the modification only for the mainmatter part.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\let\ttl@save@mkchapOrig\@makechapterhead
\let\ttl@save@mkschapOrig\@makeschapterhead

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filleft\Large}
  {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
  {5ex}
  {\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-15pt}
  {60pt}

\let\ttl@save@mkchapFormat\@makechapterhead
\let\ttl@save@mkschapFormat\@makeschapterhead

\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
   \let\@makechapterhead\ttl@save@mkchapOrig%
   \let\@makeschapterhead\ttl@save@mkschapOrig}

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
   \let\@makechapterhead\ttl@save@mkchapFormat%
   \let\@makeschapterhead\ttl@save@mkschapFormat}

\g@addto@macro\backmatter{%
   \let\@makechapterhead\ttl@save@mkchapOrig%
   \let\@makeschapterhead\ttl@save@mkschapOrig}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
Bla
\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, egreg. But when I tried it, table of contents, list of figures were also at the right-hand side rather than the left-hand side as I expected. Can you help me?

Comment: @Justlife I believe that the format of the chapter headings should be the same across the document. Why should they be different?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a standard form in my school that I have to follow.

Comment: @Justlife I wrote to Marco that I see no reason whatsoever for changing style; but I didn't consider schools' standards that, as usual, know nothing about typography. `:(`